# Avoiding same batch of drives being mirrored in a mdraid 10 Linux array

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm, raid10, synology

```
root@RS3617RPxs:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raidF1]
md3 : active raid10 sde3[8] sdl3[7] sdk3[6] sdj3[5] sdi3[4] sdh3[3] sdg3[2] sdf3[1]
      15608786176 blocks super 1.2 64K chunks 2 near-copies [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]

md2 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      971940544 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[9] sde2[1] sdf2[2] sdg2[3] sdh2[4] sdi2[5] sdj2[6] sdk2[7] sdl2[8]
      2097088 blocks [12/10] [UUUUUUUUUU__]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[7] sdb1[9] sde1[0] sdf1[2] sdg1[6] sdh1[4] sdi1[1] sdj1[8] sdk1[3] sdl1[5]
      2490176 blocks [12/10] [UUUUUUUUUU__]

unused devices: <none>
root@RS3617RPxs:~#
```

I've put the same drives as sde, sdg and sdi, slots 5, 7 and 9. I was hoping slot 5 would mirror slot 6, etc. to avoid the same batch being mirrored.

But it doesn't show a nested raid 0 on a raid 1, which I expected with raid 10.

```
/dev/md3:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Thu Jul 20 12:22:40 2017
     Raid Level : raid10
     Array Size : 15608786176 (14885.70 GiB 15983.40 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3902196544 (3721.42 GiB 3995.85 GB)
   Raid Devices : 8
  Total Devices : 8
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Jul 25 15:13:37 2017
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 8
Working Devices : 8
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 64K

           Name : RS3617RPxs:3  (local to host RS3617RPxs)
           UUID : 2d64bc68:f05d7040:c6cf8498:6d1dfa73
         Events : 44318

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       8       8       67        0      active sync set-A   /dev/sde3
       1       8       83        1      active sync set-B   /dev/sdf3
       2       8       99        2      active sync set-A   /dev/sdg3
       3       8      115        3      active sync set-B   /dev/sdh3
       4       8      131        4      active sync set-A   /dev/sdi3
       5       8      147        5      active sync set-B   /dev/sdj3
       6       8      163        6      active sync set-A   /dev/sdk3
       7       8      179        7      active sync set-B   /dev/sdl3
```

Comment: While Linux RAID10 is somewhat similar to a 'standard' RAID10, it isn't.  It has some interesting features and enhancements (see near vs far copies).

Comment: Linux MDRAID RAID10 is not a nested RAID level, rather is a *native* level. That said, to have a look at your physical disks topology, please show the output of `mdadm -D /dev/md3`

Comment: Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/xPcpjvJY